# How to create semigroup for Boolean when using scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz

I am using scalaz for some validation, and somewhere in code there are boolean conditions. A sample is shown below:

```
import scalaz._, std.AllInstances._

object Temporary {

  def validate(x: Int): scalaz.Validation[List[String], Boolean] = {
    try {
      if (x < 10) {
        scalaz.Success(true)
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("why oh why")
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => scalaz.Failure(List(e.getMessage))
    }
  }


  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = validate(1) +++ validate(10)
    println(x)

    val y = List(1,2,4,10).map(validate(_)).reduce(_ +++ _)
    println(y)
  }

}
```

I am getting following compilation errors.

```
Error:(21, 25) could not find implicit value for parameter M1: scalaz.Semigroup[Boolean]
    val x = validate(1) +++ validate(10)
                        ^
```

I cant figure out how to fix this error. Any pointers?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answer from @Travis Brown, here is what fixed it for this example. I added these two lines within the object

```
  import scalaz.Semigroup, scalaz.std.anyVal.booleanInstance.conjunction
  implicit val booleanSemigroup: Semigroup[Boolean] = conjunction
```

And now it gives correct validations:

```
Failure(List(why oh why))
Failure(List(why oh why))
```

So cool!

Answer (score 8):

There's arguably not a unique semigroup for booleans—both conjunction and disjunction are candidates for the append operation—so Scalaz doesn't provide a `Semigroup[Boolean]`. It does provide `Conjunction` and `Disjunction` tags, and if you add the tag to the static type of your `Boolean` values (which has no runtime overhead), you can get an instance for the specified operation:

```
import scalaz.{ @@, Validation }
import scalaz.Tags.Conjunction

object Temporary {

  def validate(x: Int): Validation[List[String], Boolean @@ Conjunction] = {
    try {
      if (x < 10) {
        scalaz.Success(Conjunction(true))
      } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("why oh why")
      }
    } catch {
      case e: Throwable => scalaz.Failure(List(e.getMessage))
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = validate(1) +++ validate(10)
    println(x)

    val y = List(1,2,4,10).map(validate(_)).reduce(_ +++ _)
    println(y)
  }
}
```

If you really, really wanted to pick one of these operations as *the* semigroup operation for booleans, you could do something like this:

```
import scalaz.Semigroup, scalaz.std.anyVal.booleanInstance.conjunction

implicit val booleanSemigroup: Semigroup[Boolean] = conjunction
```

And then:

```
scala> import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._
import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._

scala> true |+| false
res1: Boolean = false
```

This is somewhat at odds with the Scalaz philosophy, though.

Comment: Using @@ to choose the semigroup instance is pretty neat. Does something comparable exist in cats?

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn Not yet, but [there's an issue](https://github.com/non/cats/issues/425) for it, and I think I remember some more recent conversation on Gitter about adding tags.